# Absolute Centering Items Within A Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center items (vertically and horizontally) within a div. I have looked around here and other places and can't seem to get anything to work. What I am looking for is to have each item centered both vertically and horizontally in its respective div. Notice that there are two navigation tiles on the left and 4 on the right (1 div per tile). The divs also have parent divs which I used to build the sticky footer. The challenge is that it needs to be responsive so I cannot used fixed pixels.

```
.absolute-center {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   }
```

The above is what I tried to get the content centered. Its not working unfortunately.
Here's the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jmc3t164/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: I've tried those answers and can't get them to work

Answer (score 0):

You have this structure (shortened for brevity)

```
    <div class='top-half'>
        <p class='absolute-center'>Time left to order</p>
    </div>
    <div class='bottom-half'>
        <p class='absolute-center'>Add Produce</p>
    </div>
```

Centering both vertically *and* horizontally is often acheieved by

```
.absolute-center {
    position: absolute; /* note */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

BUT this requires that the parent element (in which the child will be centered) has `position:relative`.

So, you need to add that

```
.top-half {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.bottom-half {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position:relative;
```

}

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jmc3t164/5/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="blahblah" style="width:90%;margin:auto 5%"> content </div><br> blahblah can be any id you want, or not necessary.<br> You definitely need a width of something, ideally less than 100%; and divide the remainder from 100 by 2 and set it as margin. ( margin: auto is for up and down margings, the 5%, or whatever is for left / right.
```

Another way is to have a class .center{text-align:center} and assign it to your Div.
Finally, yet another is to insert a div under your position relevant div and style it with 'text-align:center.

Comment: thanks! how would you recommend centering it vertically?

Comment: <style>
html, body {width: 99.7%; height: 99.7%;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; border:.2em solid red">
<div style="position:relative;top:2%;left:0%;height:90%;width:90%;margin:auto 5%;border:.2em solid green">
<div style="text-align:center;position:absolute;top:4%;left:0%;height:44%;width:90%;margin:auto 5%;border:.2em solid aqua">
just cntrd
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;position:absolute;top:50%;left:0%;height:42%;width:90%;margin:auto 5%;border:.2em solid maroon">
<div style="width:100%;height:80%;margin:10% auto;">
centrd, horz and vert
</div>
</div>
</div>